# how to change url rewrite by .htacces with .php extention

Tags: php, .htaccess

my website is,

> http://localhost/mywebsite/page.php?id=123

using .htaccess i changes my url like this

> http://localhost/mywebsite/newpostof2016

but i want like this final url

> localhost/mywebsite/newpostof2016.php

current using .htacces code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$1
```

Comment: why do you want the extension? Most cases its probably better to remove it

Comment: Our projects seo is running according to static web page and now i have to create dynamic website so we have to develop according to running url.

Comment: why cant you add permanent redirects to the pages and move away from .php convention?

Comment: SEO team need links with .php because seo team already worked and working with .php extention links

Comment: seo team should know better! :(

Answer (score 0):

does this work? It should add .php to all files even if they arent php files

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

N.B. there are many reasons as to why you wouldn't want this behavior. I can't think of a case where this would benefit UX

Comment: Dear sir there are no any changes in url by your code.

Comment: what about placing it above all the other rules?

Answer (score 0):

This rule should do it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mywebsite/newpostof2016\.php$ /mywebsite/page.php?id=123 [L]
```